# What is this number which is seen in the decompiled aspecj code?

Tags: aspectj

I've compiled and weaved java and aj file.
And then I've decompiled class files to each java and aj file.

From recovered file, I can see the same number '$1$8e6adf60'.

**Decompiled java**

```
CarAspect.aspectOf().ajc$before$car_CarAspect$1$8e6adf60();
```

**Decompiled aj**

```
public void ajc$before$car_CarAspect$1$8e6adf60()
{
    System.out.println("The car color has changed!");
}
```

Could you let me know what the number means?

Can I use this number to clarify the unique weaving?

Thanks for your advice in advance.

Goh.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The number after the first dollar is the advice number within the aspect. The number after the second dollar is the hashcode of the pointcut text related to the advice. For example:

```
public aspect Code {
  before(): execution(* *(..)) {}
  before(): execution(* *(..)) {}
  before(): execution(* m(..)) {}
}
```

`javap Code.class`

```
public void ajc$before$Code$1$3444dde4();
public void ajc$before$Code$2$3444dde4();
public void ajc$before$Code$3$a6998f81();
```

Advice numbers 1, 2 and 3.  Notice the hash codes elements for the first two advice members are the same because the pointcuts are the same.

> Can I use this number to clarify the unique weaving?

Not quite sure what you mean by this, but hopefully you can work out whether you can based on my description

History of the numbers...

We (AspectJ) actually use these numbers to make incremental compilation swifter. Originally we used the 'source line' of the advice in the original aspect source file as the name suffix. That was very fragile. If you just added an empty line to the start of the file, all the generated aspect members would change name because this number changed (the line number increased). If that happened then we had to re-weave the whole system because all the calls to these guys had to be updated. We needed something more robust. So we came up with this.  Using the first number means two before advices with the same pointcut text don't have names that clash.  Combined with the second number we have a name that will not change if you alter the white space in your source aspect. The only thing that really changes it is if you alter the pointcut - and, of course, if you change the pointcut then we need to re-weave everything anyway as it may now match more/less than before.

Comment: Dear Clement, Thanks for your information. Your information would be so helpful to clarify my questions about aspectj.